# Your client does not have permission to get URL / from this server. That’s all we know

Tags: android, firebase, google-developers-console

guys i get this error first at my android app a i thought its a android related problem but them i head to my fire base console but then i found that message again on the site
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is because of the US sanction againts some countries. you can use [shecan.ir](https://shecan.ir) dns configuration to bypass it.